# Sending Emails to multiple comma separated email addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Hi I want to send emails to all the email comma addresses entered in text field. I have following controller  for  doing so.

```
 def send_invites  #friend invites
     @emails_txt = params[:emails_txt]
     @emails = @emails_txt.split(/\s*,\s*/)
      @ve = []
      @emails.each do |email|
         if email =~ /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z-]+.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/
           @ve << email
        end
      end
@all_ok = true
@errors = []

    @ve.each do |email|

        @invitation = Invitation.new
        @invitation.sender = current_user
        @invitation.recipient_email = email

      if @invitation.save
        UserMailer.invitation_notification(current_user, @invitation, new_user_registration_url+"/#{@invitation.token}").deliver
      else          
        @all_ok = "false"
        @errors << @invitation.errors       
      end
   end
end
```

It was working fine but now it is giving error as follows

```
NoMethodError in InvitationsController#send_invites 
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

whats the problem  please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are perhaps referencing a nil object in your email view.

I would look in your view for the `UserMailer#invitation_controller` action and see where you reference `username`.

Then, once you found that, trace back the object and find out why its nil, then add some testing around that (i.e. `if current_user.nil?` ...).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I think you are right. I'm getting signed out when I fetch the list of email addresses and thats why the `current_user` becomes nil.

Comment: It was because I was using normal html form instead of form_for tag of rails. Using form_for tag automatically includes your application token within the form which is of great importance regarding security concerns.